# When is the best time to terminate a web worker in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, web-worker

I use web worker with vuejs to do some complicated calculations. I have two ways to terminate workers.

1. In beforeDestroy lifestyle

```
export default {
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.worker && this.worker.terminate()
  },
  watch: {
    data(data) {
      if (!this.worker) {
        this.worker = new Worker('worker_url')
        this.worker.addEventListener('message', () => {
          // do something
        })
      }
      this.worker.postMessage(data)
    }
  }
}
```

2. After receiving message

```
export default {
  watch: {
    data(data) {
      const worker = new Worker('url')
      worker.addEventListener('message', () => {
        // do something
        worker.terminate()
      })
      worker.postMessage(data)
    }
  }
}
```

And, in this example, worker creates a thread and keep until `terminate` method being called.

I wanna know which method is better and why.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you expect your worker to send more than one message?

Comment: Of course, source data will be updated automatically at an uncertain time.

Comment: Then as long as you need it, don't terminate it.